# What if IOPCServer is not released?

Tags: c++, opc

I have developed OPC clients in c++ using OPC interfaces.

When OPC client is disconnected to OPC Server, `IOPCServer` interface is released on my code.
However, releasing `IOPCServer` takes some times.
To reduce to the time, I'm trying not to release `IOPCServer` and just fill in with null.
What if `IOPCServer` is not released? Is there any way to reduce release time?

Answer (score 0):

If you do not release IOPCServer (or, any other server interface), the server may show memory leak over time, and it will not be able to recognize that no clients are using it. Servers that are implemented as out-of-process local servers (and not running as a service) will therefore never terminate, unless you "kill" the process.